# I am unable to access audio files on ios using expo-media-library

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, media-library

I'm trying to fetch all the songs on a user's phone using expo-media-library like this:

```
const getAudioFiles = async () => {
    let media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      mediaType: "audio",
    });
    media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      mediaType: "audio",
      first: media.totalCount,
    });
    setTotalAudioCount(media.totalCount);
    setAudioFiles([...audioFiles, ...media.assets]);
  };
```

It fetches successfully on android, but on an iPhone, it returns an empty array with no errors (but there are actually audio files on the phone!)

Any help on this will be really appreciated

Comment: Could it be a permission issue? Does the code request media access beforehand as mentioned in Expo media library docs?

Comment: Yes, it does. And I granted the permission to it.

Comment: Is that even a thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563430/expo-medialibrary-how-to-request-permission-to-access-apple-music-and-audio-fil and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72653616/fix-expo-media-library-to-load-audio-and-dont-show-pop-up-permission suggest otherwise.

Comment: Actually, this is interesting: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/apple-musickit-and-api

Answer (score 0):

Changed `mediaType`

```
const getAudioFiles = async () => {
  const media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
    mediaType: MediaLibrary.MediaType.audio, // Changed mediaType
    first: media.totalCount,
  });
  setTotalAudioCount(media.totalCount);
  setAudioFiles([...audioFiles, ...media.assets]);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I just did this, still doesn't show any audio files on iphone

Comment: Check by removing `first:media.totalCount` , then try

Comment: Uhh.. no changes still. Could it be a compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should run the app on an actual device and it will work because I try it on the IOS simulator and does not work.