# Expo MediaLibrary: how to request permission to access apple music and audio files on ios?

Tags: react-native, expo

When I call `MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();` it only asks permission to access my photos, how can I make a request for getting the permission to access audio files on ios?

Comment: There are some claims accessing audio files should be possible, but the answer to this post does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202236/i-am-unable-to-access-audio-files-on-ios-using-expo-media-library. Maybe Apple just won't allow it?

Comment: Actually, this is interesting: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/apple-musickit-and-api