# Fix expo-media-library to load audio, and don't show pop up permission

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm learning to create app music by Expo, but when I use expo-media-library, it doesn't show popup permission, so can't read file music on my devices.

File AudioProvider:

```
import { Alert, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component,createContext } from 'react';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';


export const AudioContext = createContext();
export class AudioProvider extends Component {

  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      audioFiles: []
    }
  }

  permissionAllert = () => {
    Alert.alert('Permission Required', 'This app needs to read audio files!', [
      {
        text: 'I am ready',
        onPress: () => this.getPermission(),
      },
      {
        text: 'cancle',
        onPress: () => this.permissionAllert(),
      },
    ]);
  };

  getAudioFiles = async () => {
    let media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      mediaType:MediaLibrary.MediaType.audio,
    });
    media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      mediaType:MediaLibrary.MediaType.audio,
      first: media.totalCount,
    })
    console.log(media.assets.length)
    this.setState({...this.state, audioFiles:media.assets})
  }
  
  getPermission = async () =>{
  // {
  //   "canAskAgain": true,
  //   "expires": "never",
  //   "granted": false,
  //   "status": "undetermined",
  // }
    const permission = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if(permission.granted){
      //get all the file
      this.getAudioFiles();
    }

    if(!permission.granted && permission.canAskAgain){
      const {status,canAskAgain} = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if(status === 'denied' && canAskAgain){
        //display alert
        this.permissionAlert()
      }

      if(status==='granted'){
        // get all the file
        this.getAudioFiles();
      }

      if(status === 'denied' && !canAskAgain){
        //display some error
      }
    }
  } 

  componentDidMounth(){
    this.getPermission()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AudioContext.Provider value={{audioFiles:this.state.audioFiles}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AudioContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default AudioProvider
```

File AudioList:

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AudioContext } from '../context/AudioProvider'


export class AudioList extends Component {
  static contextType = AudioContext
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {this.context.audioFiles.map(item => <Text key={item.id}>{item.filename}</Text>)}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  }
})

export default AudioList
```

File App:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AudioProvider from './app/context/AudioProvider';
import HomeNavigation from './app/navigation/HomeNavigation';

export default function App(){  
  return(
    <AudioProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <HomeNavigation/>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AudioProvider>
  )
}
```

I'm use:
expo (45.0), expo-media-library (14.1.0), react (17.0.2), react-native (0.68)

My Github:
https://github.com/MT1607/Project

Comment: check `AudioProvider` I see `componentDidMounth(){
    this.getPermission()
  }` spelling mistake.
"Sai chính tả"

Comment: And shouldn't use both fuction component and class component in a project.

Comment: There are some claims accessing audio files should be possible, but the answer to this post does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202236/i-am-unable-to-access-audio-files-on-ios-using-expo-media-library. Maybe Apple just won't allow it?

Comment: Actually, this is interesting: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/apple-musickit-and-api

Comment: did your issue resolve I am having the same problem.